algorithm for generating all the standard Young tableaux
Is there any good algorithm for generating all the standard Young tableaux for a partition of $n$?
I want to check the hook length formula by numerical experiment. But first I need an algorithm to generate all the standard Young tableaux.

In the past I've done this by recursive descent on the largest part of $n$.  Does more need to be said about this?

@hardmath   you mean you generated the standard tableaux of size 1, 2, 3, ,,, n, successively? Are you sure this is the fastest algorithm?

@poisson then, the question is probably missing at least 2 things: a) what $n$ are you interested in? 2) Do you really need the fastest algorithm?

This Javascript applet by Prof. Lauren Williams may give you a chance to refine what you are asking for.

There's a section on this in Constructive Combinatorics by Stanton and White.

@AntonMenshov   I do not large $n$. I am just inclined to implement a clever algorithm.
